# Probability of a win between a faceoff

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's say two people are competing in a tournament. Player A has historically won $50%$ of his tournament games. Player B has won $40%$. What is the probability Player A beats Player B?

> My intuition is to assume those probabilities will hold in this next
> game. The case where Player A wins and Player B loses is $0.5\cdot0.6$ and the probability of the opposite occurring is $0.5\cdot0.4$ Resulting in $\frac{0.5\cdot0.6}{0.5\cdot0.6 + 0.5\cdot0.4} = 0.6$ ($60%$% Player A wins) Intuitively, this makes sense as to why Player B's win chance is unaffected. Player is seems to be an average player from winning exactly half his games. Let me know if there are any flaws in my logic.

Comment: I don't see a percentage in the given statement, maybe it's missing? Otherwise, the questions seems woefully under specified. If A won 50 games out of 1000, but won 40 out of 40, would you still think A is the favorite?

Comment: I updated it, 60% chance Player A wins. This is how the question was phrased to me. Based off what I have, I am making the assumption that Player A has a 50% chance of winning any given game in the tournament and Player B has a 40% chance of winning any given game in the tournament. What are their likelihoods versus each other?